# PHP Regex help - very confused on how to structure this

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of strings (the numbers are line numbers not included in the string!)

```
1. 2-1-44-1 WORD
2. 02-00-1030-1 WORD2
3. EKFOK (GI (I  I((II( 
4. 100-01-1-100 WORD3
5. 01 / 1-1-2-4 WORD4
6. 401 / 100-230-3-3 WORD5
.
.
.
```

I want to be able to choose only lines 1,2,4,5 and 6 from the list which have the structure:

```
{STRING[NUM] / }STRING[NUM]-STRING[NUM]-STRING[NUM]-STRING[NUM] STRING[A-Z-NUM]
```

Where the {STRING[NUM] / } is optional.

So I write:

```
if(preg_match("[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9] [a-zA-Z0-9]", $line))
    echo $line . '<br>';
```

But it says unknown modifier `-`. I try to escape the `-` but it still gives me problems.

I was thinking to use the expression I have:

```
"[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9] [a-zA-Z0-9]"
```

Then OR it to get the optional front part:

```
([0-9] / [0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9] [a-zA-Z0-9])|([0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9] [a-zA-Z0-9])
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close it should be

```
if(preg_match('/\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+\s+[a-zA-Z\d]+/', $line))
```

`\d` is simpilar to `[0-9]`

`+` means match 1 to many characters

`\s+` means match 1 to many space

Comment: Well that syntax is definitely new to me, thanks. The regex works great however when I have a string: "1-1-1-1 WORD EXTRACRAPAFTER" if it has stuff after it I don't want it returned. How can I cap that at the end?

Comment: `1-1-1-1 WORD EXTRACRAPAFTER` would match `1-1-1-1 WORD` with the above regex..what do you want to match or not match..

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern

```
[0-9]+(-[0-9]+){3}\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

or

```
\d+(-\d+){3}\s[a-zA-Z\d]+
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^(\d+ / )?\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+ \w+$
```

Answer (score 0):

I've take the regexp from @kuya_John, than I modified to return an array with **all** the match (optional parts too).

```
$p="#((\d+\s+/\s+|)(\d+(-\d+){3}\s[a-zA-Z\d]+\n)|.*\n)#ismU";
$b=file_get_contents('text_to_parse.txt');
preg_match_all($p,$b,$m));

//var_dump($m);
echo "line 1,6 \"full\" match\n";
echo "1: ".trim($m[0][0])."\n";
echo "2: ".trim($m[0][1])."\n";
echo "4: ".trim($m[0][3])."\n";
echo "5: ".trim($m[0][4])."\n";
echo "6: ".trim($m[0][5])."\n";

echo "line 5,6 \"base\" part\n";
echo "5: ".trim($m[3][4])."\n";
echo "6: ".trim($m[3][5])."\n";

echo "line 5,6 \"optional\" part\n";
echo "5: ".trim($m[2][4])."\n";
echo "6: ".trim($m[2][5])."\n";
```